# Avoid sql injection in Devexpress Grid where\filter condidtion

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-injection, dapper

Im using Devexpress Grid to show my result for final users.

since im using remote mode , i should filter my own result on server based on grid fiter.

I made custom JS swtich\case to make SQL where condition based on filter result like this :

```
   let whereClause = '';

        if (loadOptions['filter']) {
            const rawFilter = loadOptions['filter'];

            let filters = null;

            if (_.isArray(rawFilter[0])) {
                filters = _.map(rawFilter, (item) => {
                    if (_.isArray(item)) {
                        if (!_.isNumber(item[2])) {
                            switch (item[1]) {
                                case 'contains':
                                    return `(${item[0]} LIKE N'%${item[2]}%')`;
                                case 'notcontains':
                                    return `(${item[0]} NOT LIKE N'%${item[2]}%')`;
                                case 'startswith':
                                    return `(${item[0]} LIKE N'${item[2]}%')`;
                                case 'endswith':
                                    return `(${item[0]} LIKE N'%${item[2]}')`;
                                default:
                                    return `(${item[0]} ${item[1]} N'${item[2]}')`;
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            return `(${item[0]} ${item[1]} ${item[2]})`;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        return item;
                    }
                });

                whereClause = _.join(filters, ' ');
            }
        }
```

And then passing the **whereClause** to controller , like : "( ColomnA like N'ABC')"

After that , using it in Store Procedure like this (passing it as SearchParam):

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE GetTestResult
    @Skip INT = 0,
    @Take INT = 400000,
    @SearchParam NVARCHAR(MAX) = null
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sqlCommand NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @sqlCommandPagination  NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @sqlCommandFinall  NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ColomnA,ColomnB,ColomnC FROM dbo.TestTable ' 


    SET @sqlCommandPagination = ' ORDER BY ColomnA asc OFFSET ' + CAST(@Skip as varchar(500)) + 
    ' ROWS FETCH NEXT ' + CAST(@Take as varchar(500)) + ' ROWS ONLY;'

    If( @SearchParam <> '' AND @SearchParam IS NOT NULL )
         Set @sqlCommandFinall = @sqlCommand + ' Where ' + @SearchParam + @sqlCommandPagination;


    If( @SearchParam = '' OR @SearchParam IS NULL )
        Set @sqlCommandFinall = @sqlCommand +  @sqlCommandPagination;


        
Execute SP_ExecuteSQL  @sqlCommandFinall;

END;
GO
```

Is there any way to make this method Sql Injection proof ?

Im Using Dapper\SqlMapper\Query Function For calling my sp from C#.

Comment: I looked up "prone". It means "likely or liable to suffer from," I don't think you want to make your code SQL Injection prone.

Comment: @PalleDue sorry for missType , the correct one is "proof".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the way it's designed.  Or at least not without carefully parsing the statement and then leveraging parameterized values and/or positively validating the components.  And doing that is much more complex and prone to error than just passing the components.

In your current design, it's trivial to inject SQL into the where or order by.  You should break this down into its components, pass those through and validate them at the backend.  So, rather than passing `ColomnA like N'ABC'` (sic) you should pass `ColomnA` (sic) and `ABC` seperately, and use parameterized queries for the values (bind them).

In the second case, many databases will not allow parameterizing order by values, so you should be sure to use positive validation in that case.